# Z-index / IE issues

Tags: internet-explorer, wordpress, z-index

I've gone through several of the posts here & elsewhere regarding IE's handling of z-index contexts and could use an extra set of eyes.

the site in question is:

I'm trying to get the #site-index span a tags to sit on top of the image header in the #branding element.

taking a look at the code, you will see I've taken a few stabs at the positioning and z-index stacking for the whole chain of DOM elements inside of Branding but IE is still fussing.

Does anything appear out of place or otherwise suffering from an obvious ommision or eror?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that you've omitted the link?

Answer (score 0):

There's no URL in your post but it sounds like you may need to stick a z-index on the #branding element even if it's using relative positioning.

Comment: Hmmm... I posted it from my phone.  Don't think I used the anchor tag, so it probably got stripped.  The site is [The Hot Pink Pen][1]


  [1]: http://thehotpinkpen.com

Comment: I've definitely tried placing a z-index on the #branding element, but no dice.  The URL again is [link](http://thehotpinkpen.com).

Comment: So, here's the heirarchy of elements: `#branding {position:relative; z-index:200;} #branding #site-title {position:absolute; z-index:10;} #branding #site-title a {position:absolute; z-index:20;`  Any ideas?

Comment: Can anyone else assist?  I've tried placing a z-index on the parent #branding div at [this site](http://thehotpinkpen.com), but I'm not getting any results.